# Ideal SPICE Model of Op-Amp with Power

Tags: operational-amplifier, spice, modeling

I know that the ideal operation amplifier model is a single voltage controlled voltage source. My question is how to extend this ideal model, in a minimal way, to account for power supply rails (V- and V+).

Comment: The way this is done in most opamp macromodels is with two diodes and two uncontrolled voltage sources added, as shown in [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IRGvd.png). That's not minimal, but I suspect Shockley's equation (from the diodes) has some convergence advantages vs using PWL like The Photon suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LTSpice offers the ability to make a VCVS with piecewise-linear transfer function:

> Syntax: Exxx n+ n- nc+ nc- table=(, , ...)
>
> A look-up table is used to specify the transfer function. The table is a list of pairs of numbers. The second value of the pair is the output voltage when the control voltage is equal to the first value of that pair. The output is linearly interpolated when the control voltage is between specified points. If the control voltage is beyond the range of the look-up table, the output voltage is extrapolated as a constant voltage of the last point of the look-up table.

(source: LTSpice help file)

With this you could make a transfer function with linear characteristic for \$-V_s/A < V_{in} < V_s/A\$, and fixed output at the supply rails (or whatever limits you think best model your op-amp) outside those bounds.

Other SPICEs likely offer similar capabilities.

Comment: In PSpice the part "opamp" is an ideal VCVS with finite power supply rails (can be modified).